# Capture screenshot of Steam page with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, screen-scraping, steam

I need to capture screenshot from steam web page, that contains trade offer error, but for this action i have to be authorized and I don't know what header send to server.
I am trying to do this with [webshot gem](https://github.com/vitalie/webshot), filling my credentials with capybara, but this not working and it captures login page

```
 ws.start_session do
  visit 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/'
  within(:css, 'form[name="logon"]') do
    fill_in 'username', {:id => 'input_username', :with => 'test'}
    fill_in 'password', {:id => 'input_password', :with => 'password'}
  end
  click_button('Sign in', exact: true)
end.capture 'https://store.steampowered.com/account', 'example.png', width: 500, height: 500, quality: 85
```

Comment: _"this is not working"_ tells us absolutely nothing. What exactly isn't working? Post code snippets of the offending code so we can see what approach you took, and why it might not work.

Comment: added code example to question, not working = make a screenshot of page but i'm not logged in (screenshot of login page)

Comment: Yes, i understand that "not working" means you don't get the desired result. But given the package DOES work, it means your implementation isnt working. Thats the part you need to show.

Comment: This is not working in right way, cause there is an example on package page with authorization and session. I wrote similar code with right credentials and don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, are you using `js: true` when running the capybara code? By default javascript is not run and this may interfere with the Steam site. More info: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit

Comment: I didn't know about that option, cause I am not using capybara directly (dependency for webshot), that's why I didn't configured it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is probably occurring because your code doesn't wait for the login to be successful before moving on to request the account page, so the request for the account page doesn't have the correct cookies set and gets redirected back to the login page.  You need to do some sort of check to make sure the login has completed.  Something like

```
ws.start_session do
  visit 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/'
  within(:css, 'form[name="logon"]') do
    fill_in 'input_username', with: 'test'
    fill_in 'input_password', with: 'password'
  end
  click_button('Sign in', exact: true)
  page.assert_text('You are now logged in!') # whatever text shows on the page after successfully logging in
end.capture 'https://store.steampowered.com/account', 'example.png', width: 500, height: 500, quality: 85
```

Comment: thx for your answer, you are right, I needed a delay after login. Now it is working.